# How to know scroll bar is at end in selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am implementing a while loop in selenium, and want to condition my while loop, so when the scroll bar is at its end of its scroll the while loop should stop. How can i code this type of condition in while loop?
Iam using Keys.DOWN and my while loop is right now set to True

My code of while loop:

```
        while True:
            self.driver.find_element_by_id('pane-side').send_keys(Keys.DOWN * 5)
            self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_2wP_Y']")
```

Comment: Does the scroll bar scrolls the entire page or part of it (means any div)?

Comment: The scroll bar can scroll the entire page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the **pseudo code** that should do the trick.

Check if the current (scrolled position+ window height) is greater than page height(-1)

```
pageHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
totalScrolledHeight = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight")

# -1 is to make sure the rounding issues
if((pageHeight-1)<=totalScrolledHeight):
   print("pass")
else:
  print("Failed")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you.
It checks if the new height is greater than the previous height. If it's True, it will continue. Else, it will break the loop.

```
pre_height = 0
new_height = 0
while True:
  time.sleep(1)
  self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 5000);")
  new_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
  if pre_height < new_height:
    print('once again')
    pre_height =  self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
  else:
    print("maybe finished?")
    break
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the condition of the while loop to check if the position of the scroll bar is at the lowest point possible.

Comment: How can i check it?, secondly i want it to be generic. Code will help